# fully maximize wpf window using windowstate

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using the following code to change the size of the screen:

```
    private void MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
        {
            switch (WindowState)
            {
                case (WindowState.Maximized):
                    {
                        WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                        break;
                    }
                case (WindowState.Normal):
                    {
                        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, when i double click as soon as the program starts, i get a small gap along the bottom of the form. To add to the confusion, when i re-size the form to any size (using drag-move), the problem is fixed. Could someone explain why this is occurring, and a possible fix to the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fully maximize your window, set `WindowStyle` to `None`, `ResizeMode` to `NoResize` and `WindowState` to `Maximized`.

---

**[Update]** The following code works fine for me (note that I have renamed your event handler since yours hides the event `System.Windows.Controls.Control.MouseDoubleClick`). It resizes from Kiosk mode (fullscreen without window chrome) to regular mode without problems:

```
private void Window_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        switch (WindowState)
        {
            case (WindowState.Maximized):
                ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize; 
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
                WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
                break;

            case (WindowState.Normal):
                ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
                WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
                WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I should have specified... The window style is set to none, and i also want to be able to switch between maximized and normal. Wouldn't your method eliminate that functionality?

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer @MariusSchulz. I went and changed my event handler to something more appropriate, and added in the re size mode, and window style lines. However, i am still having the same issue... I've been ruling out the code that manipulates the screen (deleting to see if it would alleviate the issue) but it seems it is not working... Any other suggestions XD

Comment: Hi again, It seems i actually found the issue. It seems a setting called sizetocontent was set to width and height, and upon elimination, it solved the issue :P thanks for the help everyone.